# page is not allowed here because it does not extend class 'System.Web.UI.MasterPage'

Tags: asp.net

I am creating a website using master page, which works fine. but after I add entity data model  and some retrieval code into the login page, it comes some errors

the code is like

```
var tombstoneQuery = from t in crnnsupContext.Tombstones.Include("ProvState")
                             where t.RegNumber == _username
                             select t;
List<Tombstone> tombstoneResult = tombstoneQuery.ToList();
Cache.Insert("Tombstone", tombstoneResult);
```

the first error is happened when i try to put the list into the Cache, the error says "Thread was being aborted. After I set cache.insert statement as a commend, this error was gone, but the next one came

```
Parser Error 
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: 'OnlineRenewal.Renewal' is not allowed here because it does not extend class 'System.Web.UI.MasterPage'.

Source Error: 


Line 1:  <%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="renewal.Master.cs" Inherits="OnlineRenewal.Renewal" %>
Line 2:  
Line 3:  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

the Renewal is the master page which i didn't do anything with it. 
anyone can help? thanks a lot

the code for renewal page. (there is noting there)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;


namespace OnlineRenewal
{
public partial class renewal : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
}




<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="renewal.Master.cs" Inherits="OnlineRenewal.Renewal" %>
```

Comment: Please show the source for the `Renewal` class.

Comment: it works fine before, i don't understand where is wrong. and error "Thread was being aborted" was weird too

Comment: What happens when you make the name of that class uppercase? `Renewal` vs `renewal`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is telling you that `OnlineRenewal.Renewal` is not a master page.

Ensure it has a `<%@ Master %>` directive at the top of the page, or change the inherits attribute of the page that is causing this error to something else.